# Possible to display X number of authors posts from another WordPress site?

Tags: posts

Okay, I'm in a bit of a situation here and I'm trying to determine if there's an easy solution to this.

The site in question is http://devwww.interfacett.com. That is the main dev site (a WordPress site), and we also have the blog site which is a separate installation of WordPress found here: http://blogs.interfacett.com.

What we'd like to do is display X number of a particular authors blog posts on the main site. So, if you went to the author's landing page on the main site we could show 3,4,5 (or whatever number we choose) of that authors latest blog posts which it would pull from the blog site (they wouldn't be the full posts, just the title, date, excerpt, etc.).

I know most people will say it would be easier if we just had ONE WordPress site for both of these (and I definitely agree), but the management wants to keep it this way for the time being, so I'm trying to figure out if there's an easy solution for this. I know it's possible, but the ways I have of doing it (via XML feeds and what not) seem overly complicated.

Comment: You can build an sort of API so that one site can pull content from another but I'd hardly think that to be less complicated than using the feeds.

Comment: If you have no access to the main sites database the feed way seems to be the best option I can think of.